# Dirac distribution representation as a finite sum of derivatives of continuous functions with compact support

Tags: distribution-theory

I've been trying to express the Dirac measure (treated as a distribution) at the origin on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ as a finite sum of derivatives of continuous functions, all of which have their support on the interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$.

Looking through existing answers on math.se, I've become aware of such representations in terms of:

1. infinite sequences of compactly-supported continuous functions
2. single continuous functions that are not compactly supported
3. finite sequences of functions that are not locally integrable.

However, I have been unable to identify a finite sequence of derivatives of continuous functions (in the sense of distributions) which are locally integrable, compactly supported, and sum to the Dirac measure. By this, I mean that there exists a sequence of functions $f_i\in\mathcal{C}_c^0{((-\epsilon,\epsilon))}$ and an integer $M:2\le{M}<\infty$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^M \int_\mathbb{R}(\partial/\partial x)^{p_i}f_i(x)\phi(x)=\phi(0)\hspace{0.25cm}\forall\phi\in\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\text{,  where  }p_i\in\mathbb{N}\hspace{0.125cm}(1\le i\le M), f_i\in L_{1,loc}(\mathbb{R}).$$
Inspiration took me in the direction of Taylor's Theorem, and the best I've been able to do is to express $\delta_0(\phi)$ as a finite sum of derivatives of $\delta_a(\phi)$ for $a$ arbitrarily close to $0$. However, this is not a distribution expressible in the above form.

(Incidentally, I believe the answer to question 922708 shows there is no solution for $M=1$. This is anticipated by the exercise I'm trying to solve (*see comment below*).)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @md2perpe It's an exercise (Exercise 24.6) in Treves, *Topological Vector Spaces, Distributions and Kernels*. As it deals with the Dirac measure it felt like an important one to cover, and it feels somehow compelling.

Comment: Do the functions have to be continuous? This is not clear from the title. If it is true for a finite $M$, then it is true with $M= 1$ by considering $f = \sum f_k$ ... could you write the exact exercise?

Comment: Sure. Here it is, verbatim - will correct above if warranted. Btw, earlier context makes clear a 'function' in the sense of distributions must come from a function in $L_{1,loc}(\mathbb{R})$. "Express the Dirac measure $\delta$ at the origin, on the real line $\mathbb{R}^1$, as a finite sum of derivatives of continuous functions, all of which have their support in the interval $]-\epsilon,\epsilon[$, ($\epsilon>0$ arbitrary). Prove $\delta$ cannot be expressed as the derivative (of some order) of a single continuous function with compact support."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $f$ and $g$ below are both continuous and determine $f''-g.$
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & (x \leq -1) \\
-\frac16 (x+1)^3 & (-1 \leq x \leq 0) \\
\frac16 (x-1)^3 & (0 \leq x \leq 1) \\
0 & (1 \leq x)
\end{cases}
$$
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & (x \leq -1) \\
-1-x & (-1 \leq x \leq 0) \\
-1+x & (0 \leq x \leq 1) \\
0 & (1 \leq x)
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time. It's been killing me, and now it seems so simple. Would be good to know how you intuited that $\phi(0)$ would remain.  By the way, I think you meant $f''-g$. Also, the last piece of $g(x)$ is $1\le x$.  Didn't want to edit directly.

Comment: I've fixed the errors. Thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: @MarkoStojovic. I just started having a look at $g$ which felt like something good to start with to do some investigations. After a while I realized that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\delta-g) = 0$ so its primitive distribution/function has compact support. But that is not continuous. The second primitive function $f$ is however continuous, and so I had found a solution. This also gives a recipe to find other solutions.